# How to check for the acceptable arguments which a function can accept without reading its code?

Tags: python, function, arguments

Is there a method to check for the possible arguments that a function can accept?

e.g.

```
def greet(name,msg): 

"""This function greets to
the person with the provided message"""
print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)
```

Output: greet("Monica","Good morning!")

The arguments that can be accepted are "name" and "msg"

Comment: To be clear, you want to know from outside the function, that the function "greet" accepts 2 arguments (name & msg)?

Comment: Yes, for example if i intend to use a library's function, I'd like to know what are the possible arguments of that function without reading the library's code @Aryerez

Comment: The intellisense in *pycharm* for example shows it to you. I didn't find a coding way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module - in particular, [inspect.getfullargspec.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec)

**For your example:**

```
import inspect

def greet(name,msg): 
    print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)

print(inspect.getfullargspec(greet))
```

**Output:**

```
FullArgSpec(args=['name', 'msg'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

As you can see, this gives you a lot of information about the function arguments.